_CT records with identical __$seqval
There is a CDC enabled table of the following form:
create table dbo.foo (
    id int not null primary key,
    a char(1), 
    b char(1), 
    c char(1), 
    d char(1), 
    e char(1),
    updated datetime not null default getdate(),
    active bit not null default 1
);
go

When querying cdc.dbo_foo_CT, I see the paired records of the following form:



__$start_lsn
__$end_lsn
__$seqval
__$operation
__$update_mask
id
a
b
c
d
e
updated
active
__$command_id




0x02
NULL
0x01
1
0xFF
1
a
b
c
NULL
NULL
12:00:00
1
1


0x02
NULL
0x01
2
0xFF
1
x
b
c
NULL
NULL
13:00:00
1
2



Given operations 1 & 2 are delete & insert respectively, I might otherwise expect this to be a full-row delete-then-reinsert pattern from an app; but there are identical values in both __$start_lsn & __$seqval. When attempting to repro a delete/re-insert in a transaction, the __$seqval still increments AFAICT. Notably a merge command produces the delete/re-insert CDC pattern but still increments the __$seqval as expected.
CDC was only recently enabled, and every record in cdc.dbo_foo_CT is a paired record of this form although other CDC enabled tables in the same database do not show this pattern.
What could be causing this behavior?

If none of the rows showing this symptom have been updated since enabling CDC, this might just be a symptom of what happens to the rows when CDC is enabled?

@AaronBertrand apologies if it's unclear from the structure of the post, but the rows are showing updates - note columns a & updated in the sample. Additionally the changes appear to take place over time as well - far longer than would intuitively make sense to me if it was from CDC initialization.

Sorry, missed that.

Was the clustered index key updated, perhaps?

@DavidBrowne-Microsoft AFAICT it is not possible to modify the PK column(s) while CDC is enabled for a table.

If there is replication in this data's ancestry, updates to index keys can be propagated as delete-insert pairs.
